# Solr Query by specific type (Exact Match or Not Exact Match option)

Tags: solr

I want to let user to choose "Exact Match" or "Not Exact Match" options for the search.
How can I do that?

I tried to create a searching field typed "string" and copyField is "text".
String is for exact match and text is for not exact match.
How can I specific the field type in the query?
Or any idea is better?

Thanks and any help is regarded.

Comment: is your user directly hitting Solr or is there a web app in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

For partial matching you can use ngrams. When the user selects "Not Exact Match" you can use the dismax handler and set all ngram fields as 'qf' in your request. [For reference](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters)